# How to get host value with .com.cy in netcore

Tags: c#, .net, url

I'm having a problem getting the host value when I have a .com.cy url.

I'm using HttpContext.Request.Host.Value and the url is [www.something.com.cy](http://www.something.com.cy), but the return value is [www.something.com](http://www.something.com) without the .cy.

Is there anyway of getting the full url?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the System.Uri class instead:

```
Uri cy = new Uri("https://www.something.com.cy");
Console.WriteLine(cy.Host);
```

output:

> [www.something.com.cy](http://www.something.com.cy)